# Writing a POSIX-compliant kernel

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel

I've wanted to write a kernel for some time now. I already have a sufficient knowledge of C and I've dabbled in x86 Assembler. You see, I've wanted to write a kernel that is POSIX-compliant in C so that *NIX applications can be potentially ported to my OS, but I haven't found many resources on standard POSIX kernel functions. I have found resources on the filesystem structure, environment variables, and more on [the Open Group's POSIX page](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm).

Unfortunately, I haven't found anything explaining what calls and kernel functions a POSIX-compliant kernel must have (in other words, what kind of internal structure must a kernel have to comply with POSIX). If anyone could find that information, please tell me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

POSIX doesn't define the *internal* structure of the kernel, the kernel-to-userspace interface, or even libc, at all. Indeed, even Windows has a POSIX-compliant subsystem. Just make sure the POSIX interfaces defined at your link there work *somehow*. Note, however, that POSIX does not require anything to be implemented specifically in the kernel - you can implement things in the C library using simpler kernel interfaces of your own design where possible, if you prefer.

It just so happens that a lot of the POSIX compliant OSes (BSD, Linux, etc) have a fairly close relationship between many of those calls and the kernel layer, but there are exceptions. For example, on Linux, a `write()` call is a direct syscall, invoking a [`sys_write()`](http://lxr.oss.org.cn/source/fs/read_write.c#L301) function in the kernel. However on Windows, `write()` is implemented in a POSIX support DLL, which translates the file descriptor to a NT handle and calls [`NtWriteFile()`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/File/NtWriteFile.html) to service it, which in turn invokes a corresponding system call in `ntoskrnl.exe`. So you have a lot of freedom in how to do things - which makes things harder, if anything :)

Answer (score 4):

The opengroup.org leaves the decisions about kernel syscalls to each implmentation.
write(), for example has to look and behave as stated, but what it calls underneath is not defined.  A lot of calls like write, read, lseek are free to call whatever entrypoint they want inside the kernel.

So, no, there really is nothing that says you have to have a certain function name with a defined set of semantics available in the kernel.  It just has to available in the C runtime library.

Comment: OK, I understand now. I hope I may be able to write the POSIX kernel correctly. Thanks for clearing that up!